# How to calculate coverage in recommender systems?

Tags: python, recommender-system

I am trying to calculate coverage metrics for a recommender system that I have designed. [This](https://gab41.lab41.org/recommender-systems-its-not-all-about-the-accuracy-562c7dceeaff)  blog post talks about how to do it. I had some difficulties in understanding the same. It says that *These metrics will be for user u of **U** users over n items out of **N** potential items in a recommendation list L. Each item has a content vector **C** of length c ...* My difficulty arises in understanding **N** and **U**. Is **U** the total number of users? Secondly, what does **N** potential items mean? Is it the list of all items that are present or is it a subset of all the items present?

I am using the Python LightFM package to generate the recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, the capital letters denote the total available. In that blog post: **U** means all users, **N** means all items but in other places is usually written **I**, and **L** means all top-n recommendation lists. "Top-n" means that the recommender system outputs a ranked list of n items, so if you had 1000 users all getting a Top-10 list, you'd have **L** length of 1000*10.

I suggest you read Ge, Mouzhi, Carla Delgado-Battenfeld, and Dietmar Jannach. "Beyond accuracy: evaluating recommender systems by coverage and serendipity." Proceedings of the fourth ACM conference on Recommender systems. ACM, 2010, at http://ls13-www.cs.tu-dortmund.de/homepage/publications/jannach/Conference_RECSYS10b.pdf instead. It's a more clearly written definition of metrics and uses more traditional recommender system notation.

Comment: The ACM paper you refer to refers to the jth recommendation time. Won't the recommendations be the same at every instance? It can only change unless there is a change in the model. So this would mean that catalog coverage would be across different models, or something of that sort.

Comment: In that paper, their "Catalog coverage" metric is defined as the count of the union of all Top-N recommendation lists for all users, divided by the count of all items that could have been recommended. I also am a bit confused by their j and N notation. An example: you have 5 items in your database: A-E. You have 3 users who got these Top-2 lists: [A,B], [B,C], and [A,C]. The union of those lists is [A,B,C] which is 3 items. 3 divided by 5 items that could have been recommended is 3/5 or 0.6. Catalog coverage is therefore 0.6.